# Linux: console blanks to white

Tags: linux, console, radeon

This problem happens on a laptop with AMD e-350 APU and built-in radeon HD 6310 graphics. It runs Slackware64 version 14.0. On the console (VTs), KMS is used with the radeon driver.

The problem occurs when using a 3.10.* series kernel. If console screen blanking is enabled (e.g., `setterm -blank` or kernel parameter `consoleblank=`) then when the screen blanks, it momentarily becomes black as it should, but after a second or less turns entirely white and remains that way until it unblanks.  I've experimented and searched the web without any success at solving this.

I will add that the screen blanks properly if either (a) KMS is disabled and the console video is configured with `vga=`, or (b) a 3.2.* series kernel is used with KMS.  These possibilities are less desirable for my use, for various reasons. I'd like to get it working right with 3.10.* kernels.

I'd welcome any suggestions. I can also give more info if needed.

Comment: I searched some more and found [this thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88501), which indicates that the problem can be fixed with the radeon parameter `backlight=0`, which is available on 3.18.* kernels and newer.

Comment: See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218556/console-timeout-blanks-to-white-instead-of-black), which has the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

I searched some more and found [this thread](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=88501), which indicates that the problem can be fixed with the radeon parameter `backlight=0`, which is available on 3.18.* kernels and newer.

I happened to have 3.18.7 to try, and that worked perfectly with `backlight0`. However there was a new problem: this kernel broke my firewall, which required a re-config and recompile to fix. Given the need to recompile, I updated the source to the latest 3.18.28 before recompiling. With this, the firewall was fixed, **but** the console blanking fix no longer worked. Now, with `backlight=0` the whole console goes permanently dark the moment that radeon is loaded. No way to get it back except reboot. If I try `backlight=1` instead, the console blanks OK the first time, but blanks to white subsequently (as described in the above-linked thread).

So, this has morphed into a related problem that needs more investigation.

Answer (score 1):

I've done some more investigation. First I looked at all the incremental patches that lead from 3.18.7 (blanking worked ok with `backlight=0`) to 3.18.28 (broken).  The most suspicious change was in the patch from .22 to .23.

So I compiled 3.18.22 and it worked with `backlight=0`. Then moving to 3.18.23, it was indeed broken: `backlight=0` leads to a permanently black screen again. Then I removed the two suspicious lines from 3.18.23's code.  They occur in file `drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/atombios_encoders.c` and are identical calls:

`atombios_set_backlight_level(radeon_encoder, dig->backlight_level);`

If I comment these calls out, and recompile, it works OK.  I suspect only one of these calls may need to be removed on any given hardware having this problem.

Finally, I want to note that I tried a newer kernel, ver 4.4.5 from Slackware64 -current.  This works well with `backlight=0`, no need to hack anything.